# Help me good SQL Ebooks

Tags: sql

I have basic knowledge about SQL. But I still have difficulty when write SQL for the complex queries. Please help me some ebooks to improve my skill to write SQL, and the way to write a good SQL for performance.

The book should have example database to practice.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have an iPhone, you can buy many excellent SQL Server books through the AppStore. Do a search for SQL, and you'll find books by Kalen Delaney and the like.

Comment: I read some SQL books but they only mention about theory. I need a lot of exercises to practice and the guide. Thanks.

Comment: Many of those books have excellent examples, which you can run yourself on the Sample Databases which Microsoft provides.